# Yii2 GridView change sort icons

Tags: yii2

I have installed yii2,I want to change GridView Sort icons and class.
How I can do this? I searched in yii2 documentation but nothing found.

Yii2 Grid Code:

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [ 
            'attribute' => 'createdate',
            'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Created'),                
            'value' => function ($data) { return '4 September 2013'; }, 
        ],

    ...

    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
  ],
]);
```

Comment: This question is open for new answer's :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `web/css/site.css` as below for ascending order(use desc for descending order). Use your own icon url.

```
a.asc:after {
content: url(link/to/images/img.jpg);
}
```

Use the below to add class to your cell

```
'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'come-class']
```

Comment: Did you try? Whats the result?

Comment: there is css issue,i changed the class.

Answer (score 0):

try create your own class extend ActionColumn

```
class myActionColumn extends ActionColumn {
    public function initDefaultButtons()
    {
        if (!isset($this->buttons['view'])) {
            $this->buttons['view'] = function ($url, $model, $key) {
                $options = array_merge([
                    'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'View'),
                    'aria-label' => Yii::t('yii', 'View'),
                    'data-pjax' => '0',
                ], $this->buttonOptions);
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', $url, $options);
            };
        }
        if (!isset($this->buttons['update'])) {
            $this->buttons['update'] = function ($url, $model, $key) {
                $options = array_merge([
                    'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Update'),
                    'aria-label' => Yii::t('yii', 'Update'),
                    'data-pjax' => '0',
                ], $this->buttonOptions);
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', $url, $options);
            };
        }
        if (!isset($this->buttons['delete'])) {
            $this->buttons['delete'] = function ($url, $model, $key) {
                $options = array_merge([
                    'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                    'aria-label' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                    'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'),
                    'data-method' => 'post',
                    'data-pjax' => '0',
                ], $this->buttonOptions);
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, $options);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and change what you need and **use this class instead of ActionColumn class**

Answer (score 0):

** You can simply add a always visible sort icon by using this script - please check pjax is used if not modify function call according**

```
$script = <<< JS
    var removeSortIcon = function(event) {
            $('[data-sort]').each(function() {
                var element = $(this);
                if(element.hasClass('desc') || element.hasClass('asc') ){
                    element.remove('span');
                }else{
                    element.append(' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>');
                }
            });
    }    
    $(document).ready(removeSortIcon);
    $(document).on('ready pjax:success', removeSortIcon);
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
```

Second way :

```
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => ['name' => SORT_ASC,'email' => SORT_ASC,'username' => SORT_ASC,],
        ],
  ]);
```

[image]